# Collecting all informations on a particular field from an Array of Objects in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

The title seems somewhat confusing, so I will try and explain this as best as possible.

I have an array of entries. Each entry has a lot of fields, but I'm only interested in 3: Location, Rating(which is between 1-5) and No. of Likes. I wish to find a simple way to sum all the ratings(e.g.: 32 people gave it a 1/5, 2 gave it a 2/5, 4  gave it a 3/5 etc.) and all the no. of likes for each and every location in the array. The given array would look like this:

```
Entry no 1: Location: 'Burgers Wonderland', Rating: 3/5, No. of Likes: 3
Entry no 2: Location: 'Burgers Wasteland', Rating 5/5, No. of Likes: 4
Entry no 3: Location: 'Burgers Wasteland', Rating 4/5, No. of Likes: 5
```

And the result I wish for should look like this:

```
Location: Burgers Wonderland
Rating 5/5: 0
Rating 4/5: 1
Rating 3/5: 1
Rating 2/5: 0
Rating 1/5: 0
No. of Likes: 8
----------------
Location: Burgers Wasteland
Rating 5/5: 1
Rating 4/5: 0
Rating 3/5: 0
Rating 2/5: 0
Rating 1/5: 0
No. of Likes: 4
```

Now, I have an idea on how to make this. But it implies a lot of for loops and not so clean code. So I would ask if there is an easier way to do this(like some sort of Set equivalent from java or something else where I could write locations['Burgers Wasteland']['noOfLikes']++)

Thank you

Comment: your data does not match the wanted output.

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code, at least what the array looks like in code

Comment: Use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).